# flutter services injection in clean architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

I am new to clean architecture in flutter,

I know that we should inject our repositories via usecases into presenters like BLoc but I don't know how to use services like an audio service, for example we should pause, resume, seek and ... from the audioServiceImpl,

does it need a usecase for each opearation like play or we should inject the service directly into BLoc ?

Answer (score 2):

You've not mentioned to the layers you've adopted from the clean architecture
and the use case you need to consider such a design, so it makes your question opinion based.

A service like audio player is
more a UI related thing and it does not contain business logic,
as it mentioned in [the clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) *use cases layer contains application specific business rules*. You should clarify how your playing file involves business logic. Although you still can use bloc for player state management.

Comment: the layers I have are: domain (entities, usecases), infrastructure (repositories, services), external (datasources, drivers), presentation (BLoc, UI)

Comment: for now, I have implemented it inside infrastructure, because it needs some persistance for audioPosition and last musics and also last index to remember them, so I think it has some application business logic, is it right ?

Comment: I think you can keep player independent in the presentation layer. In your player bloc, send a request through equivalent use case to fetch the files' play state and then initialize player. When a player event is received in your bloc you can send updated play state to bellow layer in order to persist it.